# Laravel 5.4 checkbox checked while updating records

Tags: laravel, checkbox

I am trying to check the checkbox from the database for the users which are associated with the selected project.

When i link the model with form, the select boxes and text box works properly. But my checkboxes are linked to the child table.

Is it possible to link with the model directly?

Here is my Code

### Blade

```
{!!Form::model($Project, ['method' => 'PATCH' ..................
@foreach ($User as $Users)
<br />{{ Form::checkbox('user_id[]', $Users->id) }} {{ $Users->name }}
@endforeach
```

### Model

```
public function users(){return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');}
```

### Controller

```
$User = User::orderBy('name','ASC')->get();
$Project = Project::find($id);
//$users = $Project->users();
//$services = $Project->services();
return view('projects.create',compact('Project', 'User'));
```

Comment: you can compare DB records like this `{{ Form::checkbox('user_id[]',($Users->id==$oldRecord ? true : false), $Users->id) }} {{ $Users->name }}`